# How can I separate data on the basis of a delimeter in SQL or Python?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, database, hiveql

I have input data as follows:

```
Column1       Column2                                                   Column3
Silver        Bridge;#400;#Pool;#410;#Garden;#427;#Lawn;#591;#Shed;#1337    Aaron
Diamond       Meadow;#492                                                   Mike
Gold          Gas;#360;#Electricity;#1991                                   Judy
```

I need to get output as follows:

```
Column1      Column2      NewColumn     Column3
Silver       Bridge        400          Aaron
Silver       Pool          410          Aaron
Silver       Garden        427          Aaron
Silver       Lawn          591          Aaron
Silver       Shed          1337         Aaron
Diamond      Meadow        492          Mike
Gold         Gas           360          Judy
Gold         Electricity   1991         Judy
```

Note: The delimiter here for separating the data is ';#'. Trying to create a new column after the first occurrence of the delimiter(;#) and a row after the second occurrence, it should continue for the data cell.

Solution could be either in SQL or Python, but preferably in SQL.
I tried a few things but in the output I was able to separate either in columns or in rows, however here we need to separate alternately in columns and rows. I think it could be done by running loop but nothing works so far.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please don't post images of text!

Comment: Well this is my first question, I dont know how to add table

Comment: I tried following in HQL: "lateral view outer explode(split(seq,'\\|')) t1 as p", but it only separates in columns, I need to get numbers to next column but text in next row as shown in my required output data

Comment: You are not going to feed a picture into Python or SQL. So please post the data in a readable format, readable for computers and humans.

Comment: Check out [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in SQL Server documentation

Comment: I'm just going to rollback to my revision. You can edit this version to add or refine your data. As an aside this is a hard question to answer. If you get an answer in several flavours of database as well as something like pandas which answer is going to be accepted as correct? I'd suggest reducing your tags to focus on a single technology.

Comment: Hi @HenryEcker, I need to feed this data in a table so solution could be in sql, python or hql doesn't matter, at the last I need to feed the refined data to table.

Comment: Hi @Squirrel, thanks but I dont think  STRING_SPLIT()  would work as it is recurring with variable times.

Answer (score 2):

One option in SQL Server is to use a bit of JSON and a conditional aggregation within a CROSS APPLY

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=deb88ba584b5878f3fe873db755d9e0d)**

```
Select A.Column1 
      ,B.Column2
      ,B.NewColumn
      ,A.Column3
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Column2   = max(case when [Key] % 2 = 0 then Value end)
                      ,NewColumn = max(case when [Key] % 2 = 1 then Value end)
                 From  OpenJSON( '["'+replace(string_escape([Column2],'json'),';#','","')+'"]' )
                 Group By [Key] / 2
             ) B
```

**Results**

[image]